# How can I get URLs and site names for a cross-site SEDE query?

Tags: support, hyperlinks, data-explorer, site-name

When doing cross-site queries on the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/), two of the main problems are 1) getting the URLs right and 2) getting the site names right. For URLs, we have constructions like the bottom half of [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/508589/better-template-for-multi-db-queries) or [this one](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/740847/networkwide-questions-per-account-ordered-by-view-count). We (Meta regulars) don't bother with site names (c'mon, everybody knows the database of [Video Production Stack Exchange](https://video.stackexchange.com/) is named StackExchange.Audio ...) but the [revision list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/359735/revisions) of the recent post [2020: a year in closing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359735/295232) speaks volumes. Even for SE staff it's difficult to get it right, see [this comment by @Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359735/2020-a-year-in-closing#comment1200658_359735):

> There's an internal instance of SEDE that suffers from the same issue as the public instance, @sonic: it has its own sites table with metadata on the databases it has imported, including name, which is never really updated. To get the proper site names for data like this, one must query the actual `Sites` table used by the system itself, which is slightly less convenient than just choosing the "run on all sites" option and letting SEDE fill it in. You can observe this same effect in some of my old posts when I was in a hurry.

The main disadvantages of the solutions employed to get the URLs (and a similar solution for site names) is that whenever a new 'exception' is needed (e.g. following a site rename), one needs to update *all* queries. Fortunately, the old URLs (e.g. https://writers.stackexchange.com) continue to be working. Is there a way we can make a community-maintained solution for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, we can. This question will receive another answer with a table containing all site names, base URLs and database names. That answer can be used in SEDE queries by reading the Markdown from its latest revision and can then be parsed to generate a temporary table with all the relevant information. [Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1360233/site-details) is how that works.

You can use that snippet and `JOIN` your cross-site query with this table. An example can be found in [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1361542/number-of-hot-network-questions-per-site?fromDate=2020-01-01&tillDate=2020-12-31), which lists the number of Hot Network Questions per site:

[image]

To check whether the site names in the table in the other answer are up to date (and all sites are included), you can run the following snippet. It will print 'Everything is OK!' if the table is correct.

```js
const key = "U4DMV*8nvpm3EOpvf69Rxw(("; // from API documentation
// Read site list in Meta post
$.get("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/posts/359796?site=meta&filter=!).EiO3YPYw&key=" + key, function (data) {
  let markdown = data.items[0].body_markdown;
  let components = markdown.split("|");
  let sites = {};
  for (var i = 9; i < components.length; i += 4) {
    sites[components[i].trim()] = components[i + 1].trim();
  }
  
  // Get site information
  $.get("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/sites?pageSize=1000&filter=!*L2qLVG5uyZ8GDTI&key=" + key, function (data) {
    var ok = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
      let url = data.items[i].site_url;
      // Some sites are deliberately excluded
      if (url == "https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com" ||
          url == "https://cs50.stackexchange.com" ||
          url == "https://cs50.meta.stackexchange.com")
        continue;
      let name = data.items[i].name;
      if (url in sites) {
        if (sites[url] != name) {
          ok = false;
          console.log("Site " + sites[url] + " has another name: " + name);
        }
        delete sites[url];
      } else {
        ok = false;
        console.log("Site " + name + " (" + url + ") is missing.");
      }
    }
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(sites)) {
      ok = false;
      console.log("Site " + value + " (" + key + ") does not exist anymore.");
    }
    if (ok) {
      console.log("Everything is OK!");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

Comment: You are inviting users to commit serial upvoting ... ;)

Comment: While I don't think it will cause issues in our use case it is worth mentioning that [*A transaction inserting multiple rows is not guaranteed to get consecutive values for the rows because other concurrent inserts might occur on the table. If values must be consecutive then the transaction should use an exclusive lock on the table*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-ver15). The query does require that the identity values are consecutive.

Comment: ... and it relies on `STRING_SPLIT` returning its values in the right order, which isn't guaranteed. Let's see what happens with the current version. I like keeping things (reasonably) simple.

Comment: I've been fiddling a bit to see if I could get that table without using temp tables: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1362177/site-details?opt.withExecutionPlan=true#executionPlan

Comment: Nice! Perhaps it's worth making a Code Golf challenge out of it :)

Answer (score 15):

The table below does not provide the solution, but the [accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/359795/295232) contains instructions how to use it. The table contains all Q&A sites that are available via SEDE. So e.g. [Area 51](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/area51/info) and [CS50](https://cs50.stackexchange.com/tour) are deliberately not included in the table.

Feel free to edit this answer when the need arises, e.g. when a site is renamed or a new beta is launched. There is a snippet in the other answer to check if the table is up-to-date. The most important thing is to realize the SEDE queries split on the pipe symbol; therefore it should **not** be used in this introductory text.

| URL | Site name | Database name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com | 3D Printing | StackExchange.3dprinting |
| https://3dprinting.meta.stackexchange.com | 3D Printing Meta | StackExchange.3dprinting.Meta |
| https://academia.stackexchange.com | Academia | StackExchange.Academia |
| https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com | Academia Meta | StackExchange.Academia.Meta |
| https://ham.stackexchange.com | Amateur Radio | StackExchange.Ham |
| https://ham.meta.stackexchange.com | Amateur Radio Meta | StackExchange.Ham.Meta |
| https://android.stackexchange.com | Android Enthusiasts | StackExchange.Android |
| https://android.meta.stackexchange.com | Android Enthusiasts Meta | StackExchange.Android.Meta |
| https://anime.stackexchange.com | Anime & Manga | StackExchange.Anime |
| https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com | Anime & Manga Meta | StackExchange.Anime.Meta |
| https://arduino.stackexchange.com | Arduino | StackExchange.Arduino |
| https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com | Arduino Meta | StackExchange.Arduino.Meta |
| https://gaming.stackexchange.com | Arqade | StackExchange.Gaming |
| https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com | Arqade Meta | StackExchange.Gaming.Meta |
| https://ai.stackexchange.com | Artificial Intelligence | StackExchange.Ai |
| https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com | Artificial Intelligence Meta | StackExchange.Ai.Meta |
| https://crafts.stackexchange.com | Arts & Crafts | StackExchange.Crafts |
| https://crafts.meta.stackexchange.com | Arts & Crafts Meta | StackExchange.Crafts.Meta |
| https://apple.stackexchange.com | Ask Different | StackExchange.Apple |
| https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com | Ask Different Meta | StackExchange.Apple.Meta |
| https://patents.stackexchange.com | Ask Patents | StackExchange.Patents |
| https://patents.meta.stackexchange.com | Ask Patents Meta | StackExchange.Patents.Meta |
| https://askubuntu.com | Ask Ubuntu | StackExchange.Ubuntu |
| https://meta.askubuntu.com | Ask Ubuntu Meta | StackExchange.Ubuntu.Meta |
| https://astronomy.stackexchange.com | Astronomy | StackExchange.Astronomy |
| https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com | Astronomy Meta | StackExchange.Astronomy.Meta |
| https://aviation.stackexchange.com | Aviation | StackExchange.Aviation |
| https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com | Aviation Meta | StackExchange.Aviation.Meta |
| https://alcohol.stackexchange.com | Beer, Wine & Spirits | StackExchange.Beer |
| https://alcohol.meta.stackexchange.com | Beer, Wine & Spirits Meta | StackExchange.Beer.Meta |
| https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com | Biblical Hermeneutics | StackExchange.Hermeneutics |
| https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com | Biblical Hermeneutics Meta | StackExchange.Hermeneutics.Meta |
| https://bicycles.stackexchange.com | Bicycles | StackExchange.Bicycles |
| https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com | Bicycles Meta | StackExchange.Bicycles.Meta |
| https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com | Bioacoustics | StackExchange.Bioacoustics |
| https://bioacoustics.meta.stackexchange.com | Bioacoustics Meta | StackExchange.Bioacoustics.Meta |
| https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com | Bioinformatics | StackExchange.Bioinformatics |
| https://bioinformatics.meta.stackexchange.com | Bioinformatics Meta | StackExchange.Bioinformatics.Meta |
| https://biology.stackexchange.com | Biology | StackExchange.Biology |
| https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com | Biology Meta | StackExchange.Biology.Meta |
| https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com | Bitcoin | StackExchange.Bitcoin |
| https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com | Bitcoin Meta | StackExchange.Bitcoin.Meta |
| https://blender.stackexchange.com | Blender | StackExchange.Blender |
| https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com | Blender Meta | StackExchange.Blender.Meta |
| https://boardgames.stackexchange.com | Board & Card Games | StackExchange.Boardgames |
| https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com | Board & Card Games Meta | StackExchange.Boardgames.Meta |
| https://bricks.stackexchange.com | Bricks | StackExchange.Bricks |
| https://bricks.meta.stackexchange.com | Bricks Meta | StackExchange.Bricks.Meta |
| https://buddhism.stackexchange.com | Buddhism | StackExchange.Buddhism |
| https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com | Buddhism Meta | StackExchange.Buddhism.Meta |
| https://cardano.stackexchange.com | Cardano | StackExchange.Cardano |
| https://cardano.meta.stackexchange.com | Cardano Meta | StackExchange.Cardano.Meta |
| https://chemistry.stackexchange.com | Chemistry | StackExchange.Chemistry |
| https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com | Chemistry Meta | StackExchange.Chemistry.Meta |
| https://chess.stackexchange.com | Chess | StackExchange.Chess |
| https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com | Chess Meta | StackExchange.Chess.Meta |
| https://chinese.stackexchange.com | Chinese Language | StackExchange.Chinese |
| https://chinese.meta.stackexchange.com | Chinese Language Meta | StackExchange.Chinese.Meta |
| https://christianity.stackexchange.com | Christianity | StackExchange.Christianity |
| https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com | Christianity Meta | StackExchange.Christianity.Meta |
| https://civicrm.stackexchange.com | CiviCRM | StackExchange.Civicrm |
| https://civicrm.meta.stackexchange.com | CiviCRM Meta | StackExchange.Civicrm.Meta |
| https://codegolf.stackexchange.com | Code Golf | StackExchange.Codegolf |
| https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com | Code Golf Meta | StackExchange.Codegolf.Meta |
| https://codereview.stackexchange.com | Code Review | StackExchange.Codereview |
| https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com | Code Review Meta | StackExchange.Codereview.Meta |
| https://coffee.stackexchange.com | Coffee | StackExchange.Coffee |
| https://coffee.meta.stackexchange.com | Coffee Meta | StackExchange.Coffee.Meta |
| https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com | Community Building | StackExchange.Moderators |
| https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com | Community Building Meta | StackExchange.Moderators.Meta |
| https://scicomp.stackexchange.com | Computational Science | StackExchange.Scicomp |
| https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com | Computational Science Meta | StackExchange.Scicomp.Meta |
| https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com | Computer Graphics | StackExchange.Computergraphics |
| https://computergraphics.meta.stackexchange.com | Computer Graphics Meta | StackExchange.Computergraphics.Meta |
| https://cs.stackexchange.com | Computer Science | StackExchange.Cs |
| https://cseducators.stackexchange.com | Computer Science Educators | StackExchange.Cseducators |
| https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com | Computer Science Educators Meta | StackExchange.Cseducators.Meta |
| https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com | Computer Science Meta | StackExchange.Cs.Meta |
| https://conlang.stackexchange.com | Constructed Languages | StackExchange.Conlang |
| https://conlang.meta.stackexchange.com | Constructed Languages Meta | StackExchange.Conlang.Meta |
| https://craftcms.stackexchange.com | Craft CMS | StackExchange.Craftcms |
| https://craftcms.meta.stackexchange.com | Craft CMS Meta | StackExchange.Craftcms.Meta |
| https://stats.stackexchange.com | Cross Validated | StackExchange.Stats |
| https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com | Cross Validated Meta | StackExchange.Stats.Meta |
| https://crypto.stackexchange.com | Cryptography | StackExchange.Crypto |
| https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com | Cryptography Meta | StackExchange.Crypto.Meta |
| https://datascience.stackexchange.com | Data Science | StackExchange.Datascience |
| https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com | Data Science Meta | StackExchange.Datascience.Meta |
| https://dba.stackexchange.com | Database Administrators | StackExchange.Dba |
| https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com | Database Administrators Meta | StackExchange.Dba.Meta |
| https://devops.stackexchange.com | DevOps | StackExchange.Devops |
| https://devops.meta.stackexchange.com | DevOps Meta | StackExchange.Devops.Meta |
| https://drones.stackexchange.com | Drones and Model Aircraft | StackExchange.Drones |
| https://drones.meta.stackexchange.com | Drones and Model Aircraft Meta | StackExchange.Drones.Meta |
| https://drupal.stackexchange.com | Drupal Answers | StackExchange.Drupal |
| https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com | Drupal Answers Meta | StackExchange.Drupal.Meta |
| https://earthscience.stackexchange.com | Earth Science | StackExchange.Earthscience |
| https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com | Earth Science Meta | StackExchange.Earthscience.Meta |
| https://ebooks.stackexchange.com | Ebooks | StackExchange.Ebooks |
| https://ebooks.meta.stackexchange.com | Ebooks Meta | StackExchange.Ebooks.Meta |
| https://economics.stackexchange.com | Economics | StackExchange.Economics |
| https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com | Economics Meta | StackExchange.Economics.Meta |
| https://electronics.stackexchange.com | Electrical Engineering | StackExchange.Electronics |
| https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com | Electrical Engineering Meta | StackExchange.Electronics.Meta |
| https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com | elementary OS | StackExchange.Elementaryos |
| https://elementaryos.meta.stackexchange.com | elementary OS Meta | StackExchange.Elementaryos.Meta |
| https://emacs.stackexchange.com | Emacs | StackExchange.Emacs |
| https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com | Emacs Meta | StackExchange.Emacs.Meta |
| https://engineering.stackexchange.com | Engineering | StackExchange.Engineering |
| https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com | Engineering Meta | StackExchange.Engineering.Meta |
| https://english.stackexchange.com | English Language & Usage | StackExchange.English |
| https://english.meta.stackexchange.com | English Language & Usage Meta | StackExchange.English.Meta |
| https://ell.stackexchange.com | English Language Learners | StackExchange.Ell |
| https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com | English Language Learners Meta | StackExchange.Ell.Meta |
| https://eosio.stackexchange.com | EOS.IO | StackExchange.Eosio |
| https://eosio.meta.stackexchange.com | EOS.IO Meta | StackExchange.Eosio.Meta |
| https://esperanto.stackexchange.com | Esperanto Language | StackExchange.Esperanto |
| https://esperanto.meta.stackexchange.com | Esperanto Language Meta | StackExchange.Esperanto.Meta |
| https://ethereum.stackexchange.com | Ethereum | StackExchange.Ethereum |
| https://ethereum.meta.stackexchange.com | Ethereum Meta | StackExchange.Ethereum.Meta |
| https://expatriates.stackexchange.com | Expatriates | StackExchange.Expatriates |
| https://expatriates.meta.stackexchange.com | Expatriates Meta | StackExchange.Expatriates.Meta |
| https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com | ExpressionEngine® Answers | StackExchange.Expressionengine |
| https://expressionengine.meta.stackexchange.com | ExpressionEngine® Answers Meta | StackExchange.Expressionengine.Meta |
| https://freelancing.stackexchange.com | Freelancing | StackExchange.Freelancing |
| https://freelancing.meta.stackexchange.com | Freelancing Meta | StackExchange.Freelancing.Meta |
| https://french.stackexchange.com | French Language | StackExchange.French |
| https://french.meta.stackexchange.com | French Language Meta | StackExchange.French.Meta |
| https://gamedev.stackexchange.com | Game Development | StackExchange.GameDev |
| https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com | Game Development Meta | StackExchange.GameDev.Meta |
| https://gardening.stackexchange.com | Gardening & Landscaping | StackExchange.Gardening |
| https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com | Gardening & Landscaping Meta | StackExchange.Gardening.Meta |
| https://genealogy.stackexchange.com | Genealogy & Family History | StackExchange.Genealogy |
| https://genealogy.meta.stackexchange.com | Genealogy & Family History Meta | StackExchange.Genealogy.Meta |
| https://gis.stackexchange.com | Geographic Information Systems | StackExchange.Gis |
| https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com | Geographic Information Systems Meta | StackExchange.Gis.Meta |
| https://german.stackexchange.com | German Language | StackExchange.German |
| https://german.meta.stackexchange.com | German Language Meta | StackExchange.German.Meta |
| https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com | Graphic Design | StackExchange.Graphicdesign |
| https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com | Graphic Design Meta | StackExchange.Graphicdesign.Meta |
| https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com | Hardware Recommendations | StackExchange.Hardwarerecs |
| https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com | Hardware Recommendations Meta | StackExchange.Hardwarerecs.Meta |
| https://hinduism.stackexchange.com | Hinduism | StackExchange.Hinduism |
| https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com | Hinduism Meta | StackExchange.Hinduism.Meta |
| https://history.stackexchange.com | History | StackExchange.History |
| https://history.meta.stackexchange.com | History Meta | StackExchange.History.Meta |
| https://hsm.stackexchange.com | History of Science and Mathematics | StackExchange.Hsm |
| https://hsm.meta.stackexchange.com | History of Science and Mathematics Meta | StackExchange.Hsm.Meta |
| https://diy.stackexchange.com | Home Improvement | StackExchange.Diy |
| https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com | Home Improvement Meta | StackExchange.Diy.Meta |
| https://homebrew.stackexchange.com | Homebrewing | StackExchange.Homebrew |
| https://homebrew.meta.stackexchange.com | Homebrewing Meta | StackExchange.Homebrew.Meta |
| https://security.stackexchange.com | Information Security | StackExchange.Security |
| https://security.meta.stackexchange.com | Information Security Meta | StackExchange.Security.Meta |
| https://iot.stackexchange.com | Internet of Things | StackExchange.Iot |
| https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com | Internet of Things Meta | StackExchange.Iot.Meta |
| https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com | Interpersonal Skills | StackExchange.Interpersonal |
| https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com | Interpersonal Skills Meta | StackExchange.Interpersonal.Meta |
| https://iota.stackexchange.com | Iota | StackExchange.Iota |
| https://iota.meta.stackexchange.com | Iota Meta | StackExchange.Iota.Meta |
| https://islam.stackexchange.com | Islam | StackExchange.Islam |
| https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com | Islam Meta | StackExchange.Islam.Meta |
| https://italian.stackexchange.com | Italian Language | StackExchange.Italian |
| https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com | Italian Language Meta | StackExchange.Italian.Meta |
| https://japanese.stackexchange.com | Japanese Language | StackExchange.Japanese |
| https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com | Japanese Language Meta | StackExchange.Japanese.Meta |
| https://joomla.stackexchange.com | Joomla | StackExchange.Joomla |
| https://joomla.meta.stackexchange.com | Joomla Meta | StackExchange.Joomla.Meta |
| https://korean.stackexchange.com | Korean Language | StackExchange.Korean |
| https://korean.meta.stackexchange.com | Korean Language Meta | StackExchange.Korean.Meta |
| https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com | Language Learning | StackExchange.Languagelearning |
| https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com | Language Learning Meta | StackExchange.Languagelearning.Meta |
| https://latin.stackexchange.com | Latin Language | StackExchange.Latin |
| https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com | Latin Language Meta | StackExchange.Latin.Meta |
| https://law.stackexchange.com | Law | StackExchange.Law |
| https://law.meta.stackexchange.com | Law Meta | StackExchange.Law.Meta |
| https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com | Lifehacks | StackExchange.Lifehacks |
| https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com | Lifehacks Meta | StackExchange.Lifehacks.Meta |
| https://linguistics.stackexchange.com | Linguistics | StackExchange.Linguistics |
| https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com | Linguistics Meta | StackExchange.Linguistics.Meta |
| https://literature.stackexchange.com | Literature | StackExchange.Literature |
| https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com | Literature Meta | StackExchange.Literature.Meta |
| https://magento.stackexchange.com | Magento | StackExchange.Magento |
| https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com | Magento Meta | StackExchange.Magento.Meta |
| https://martialarts.stackexchange.com | Martial Arts | StackExchange.Martialarts |
| https://martialarts.meta.stackexchange.com | Martial Arts Meta | StackExchange.Martialarts.Meta |
| https://mathematica.stackexchange.com | Mathematica | StackExchange.Mathematica |
| https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com | Mathematica Meta | StackExchange.Mathematica.Meta |
| https://math.stackexchange.com | Mathematics | StackExchange.Math |
| https://matheducators.stackexchange.com | Mathematics Educators | StackExchange.Matheducators |
| https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com | Mathematics Educators Meta | StackExchange.Matheducators.Meta |
| https://math.meta.stackexchange.com | Mathematics Meta | StackExchange.Math.Meta |
| https://mathoverflow.net | MathOverflow | StackExchange.Mathoverflow |
| https://meta.mathoverflow.net | MathOverflow Meta | StackExchange.Mathoverflow.Meta |
| https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com | Matter Modeling | StackExchange.Materials |
| https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com | Matter Modeling Meta | StackExchange.Materials.Meta |
| https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com | Medical Sciences | StackExchange.Health |
| https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com | Medical Sciences Meta | StackExchange.Health.Meta |
| https://meta.serverfault.com | Meta Server Fault | ServerFault.Meta |
| https://meta.stackexchange.com | Meta Stack Exchange | StackExchange.Meta |
| https://meta.stackoverflow.com | Meta Stack Overflow | StackOverflow.Meta |
| https://meta.superuser.com | Meta Super User | SuperUser.Meta |
| https://judaism.stackexchange.com | Mi Yodeya | StackExchange.Judaism |
| https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com | Mi Yodeya Meta | StackExchange.Judaism.Meta |
| https://monero.stackexchange.com | Monero | StackExchange.Monero |
| https://monero.meta.stackexchange.com | Monero Meta | StackExchange.Monero.Meta |
| https://mechanics.stackexchange.com | Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair | StackExchange.Garage |
| https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com | Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair Meta | StackExchange.Garage.Meta |
| https://movies.stackexchange.com | Movies & TV | StackExchange.Movies |
| https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com | Movies & TV Meta | StackExchange.Movies.Meta |
| https://musicfans.stackexchange.com | Music Fans | StackExchange.Musicfans |
| https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com | Music Fans Meta | StackExchange.Musicfans.Meta |
| https://music.stackexchange.com | Music: Practice & Theory | StackExchange.Music |
| https://music.meta.stackexchange.com | Music: Practice & Theory Meta | StackExchange.Music.Meta |
| https://mythology.stackexchange.com | Mythology & Folklore | StackExchange.Mythology |
| https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com | Mythology & Folklore Meta | StackExchange.Mythology.Meta |
| https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com | Network Engineering | StackExchange.Networkengineering |
| https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com | Network Engineering Meta | StackExchange.Networkengineering.Meta |
| https://opendata.stackexchange.com | Open Data | StackExchange.Opendata |
| https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com | Open Data Meta | StackExchange.Opendata.Meta |
| https://opensource.stackexchange.com | Open Source | StackExchange.Opensource |
| https://opensource.meta.stackexchange.com | Open Source Meta | StackExchange.Opensource.Meta |
| https://or.stackexchange.com | Operations Research | StackExchange.Or |
| https://or.meta.stackexchange.com | Operations Research Meta | StackExchange.Or.Meta |
| https://parenting.stackexchange.com | Parenting | StackExchange.Parenting |
| https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com | Parenting Meta | StackExchange.Parenting.Meta |
| https://money.stackexchange.com | Personal Finance & Money | StackExchange.Money |
| https://money.meta.stackexchange.com | Personal Finance & Money Meta | StackExchange.Money.Meta |
| https://pets.stackexchange.com | Pets | StackExchange.Pets |
| https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com | Pets Meta | StackExchange.Pets.Meta |
| https://philosophy.stackexchange.com | Philosophy | StackExchange.Philosophy |
| https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com | Philosophy Meta | StackExchange.Philosophy.Meta |
| https://photo.stackexchange.com | Photography | StackExchange.Photography |
| https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com | Photography Meta | StackExchange.Photography.Meta |
| https://fitness.stackexchange.com | Physical Fitness | StackExchange.Fitness |
| https://fitness.meta.stackexchange.com | Physical Fitness Meta | StackExchange.Fitness.Meta |
| https://physics.stackexchange.com | Physics | StackExchange.Physics |
| https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com | Physics Meta | StackExchange.Physics.Meta |
| https://poker.stackexchange.com | Poker | StackExchange.Poker |
| https://poker.meta.stackexchange.com | Poker Meta | StackExchange.Poker.Meta |
| https://politics.stackexchange.com | Politics | StackExchange.Politics |
| https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com | Politics Meta | StackExchange.Politics.Meta |
| https://portuguese.stackexchange.com | Portuguese Language | StackExchange.Portuguese |
| https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com | Portuguese Language Meta | StackExchange.Portuguese.Meta |
| https://pm.stackexchange.com | Project Management | StackExchange.Pm |
| https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com | Project Management Meta | StackExchange.Pm.Meta |
| https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com | Proof Assistants | StackExchange.Proofassistants |
| https://proofassistants.meta.stackexchange.com | Proof Assistants Meta | StackExchange.Proofassistants.Meta |
| https://psychology.stackexchange.com | Psychology & Neuroscience | StackExchange.Cogsci |
| https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com | Psychology & Neuroscience Meta | StackExchange.Cogsci.Meta |
| https://puzzling.stackexchange.com | Puzzling | StackExchange.Puzzling |
| https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com | Puzzling Meta | StackExchange.Puzzling.Meta |
| https://quant.stackexchange.com | Quantitative Finance | StackExchange.Quant |
| https://quant.meta.stackexchange.com | Quantitative Finance Meta | StackExchange.Quant.Meta |
| https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com | Quantum Computing | StackExchange.Quantumcomputing |
| https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com | Quantum Computing Meta | StackExchange.Quantumcomputing.Meta |
| https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com | Raspberry Pi | StackExchange.Raspberrypi |
| https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com | Raspberry Pi Meta | StackExchange.Raspberrypi.Meta |
| https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com | Retrocomputing | StackExchange.Retrocomputing |
| https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com | Retrocomputing Meta | StackExchange.Retrocomputing.Meta |
| https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com | Reverse Engineering | StackExchange.Reverseengineering |
| https://reverseengineering.meta.stackexchange.com | Reverse Engineering Meta | StackExchange.Reverseengineering.Meta |
| https://robotics.stackexchange.com | Robotics | StackExchange.Robotics |
| https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com | Robotics Meta | StackExchange.Robotics.Meta |
| https://rpg.stackexchange.com | Role-playing Games | StackExchange.Rpg |
| https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com | Role-playing Games Meta | StackExchange.Rpg.Meta |
| https://russian.stackexchange.com | Russian Language | StackExchange.Russian |
| https://russian.meta.stackexchange.com | Russian Language Meta | StackExchange.Russian.Meta |
| https://salesforce.stackexchange.com | Salesforce | StackExchange.Salesforce |
| https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com | Salesforce Meta | StackExchange.Salesforce.Meta |
| https://scifi.stackexchange.com | Science Fiction & Fantasy | StackExchange.Scifi |
| https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com | Science Fiction & Fantasy Meta | StackExchange.Scifi.Meta |
| https://cooking.stackexchange.com | Seasoned Advice | StackExchange.Cooking |
| https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com | Seasoned Advice Meta | StackExchange.Cooking.Meta |
| https://serverfault.com | Server Fault | ServerFault |
| https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com | SharePoint | StackExchange.Sharepoint |
| https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com | SharePoint Meta | StackExchange.Sharepoint.Meta |
| https://dsp.stackexchange.com | Signal Processing | StackExchange.Dsp |
| https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com | Signal Processing Meta | StackExchange.Dsp.Meta |
| https://sitecore.stackexchange.com | Sitecore | StackExchange.Sitecore |
| https://sitecore.meta.stackexchange.com | Sitecore Meta | StackExchange.Sitecore.Meta |
| https://skeptics.stackexchange.com | Skeptics | StackExchange.Skeptics |
| https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com | Skeptics Meta | StackExchange.Skeptics.Meta |
| https://solana.stackexchange.com | Solana | StackExchange.Solana |
| https://solana.meta.stackexchange.com | Solana Meta | StackExchange.Solana.Meta |
| https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com | Software Engineering | StackExchange.Programmers |
| https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com | Software Engineering Meta | StackExchange.Programmers.Meta |
| https://sqa.stackexchange.com | Software Quality Assurance & Testing | StackExchange.Sqa |
| https://sqa.meta.stackexchange.com | Software Quality Assurance & Testing Meta | StackExchange.Sqa.Meta |
| https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com | Software Recommendations | StackExchange.Softwarerecs |
| https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com | Software Recommendations Meta | StackExchange.Softwarerecs.Meta |
| https://sound.stackexchange.com | Sound Design | StackExchange.Sound |
| https://sound.meta.stackexchange.com | Sound Design Meta | StackExchange.Sound.Meta |
| https://space.stackexchange.com | Space Exploration | StackExchange.Space |
| https://space.meta.stackexchange.com | Space Exploration Meta | StackExchange.Space.Meta |
| https://spanish.stackexchange.com | Spanish Language | StackExchange.Spanish |
| https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com | Spanish Language Meta | StackExchange.Spanish.Meta |
| https://sports.stackexchange.com | Sports | StackExchange.Sports |
| https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com | Sports Meta | StackExchange.Sports.Meta |
| https://stackapps.com | Stack Apps | StackApps |
| https://stackoverflow.com | Stack Overflow | StackOverflow |
| https://pt.stackoverflow.com | Stack Overflow em Português | StackOverflow.Br |
| https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com | Stack Overflow em Português Meta | StackOverflow.Br.Meta |
| https://es.stackoverflow.com | Stack Overflow en español | StackOverflow.Es |
| https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com | Stack Overflow Meta en español | StackOverflow.Es.Meta |
| https://ru.stackoverflow.com | Stack Overflow на русском | StackOverflow.Ru |
| https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com | Stack Overflow на русском Meta | StackOverflow.Ru.Meta |
| https://stellar.stackexchange.com | Stellar | StackExchange.Stellar |
| https://stellar.meta.stackexchange.com | Stellar Meta | StackExchange.Stellar.Meta |
| https://substrate.stackexchange.com | Substrate and Polkadot | StackExchange.Substrate |
| https://substrate.meta.stackexchange.com | Substrate and Polkadot Meta | StackExchange.Substrate.Meta |
| https://superuser.com | Super User | SuperUser |
| https://sustainability.stackexchange.com | Sustainable Living | StackExchange.Sustainability |
| https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com | Sustainable Living Meta | StackExchange.Sustainability.Meta |
| https://tex.stackexchange.com | TeX - LaTeX | StackExchange.Tex |
| https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com | TeX - LaTeX Meta | StackExchange.Tex.Meta |
| https://tezos.stackexchange.com | Tezos | StackExchange.Tezos |
| https://tezos.meta.stackexchange.com | Tezos Meta | StackExchange.Tezos.Meta |
| https://outdoors.stackexchange.com | The Great Outdoors | StackExchange.Outdoors |
| https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com | The Great Outdoors Meta | StackExchange.Outdoors.Meta |
| https://workplace.stackexchange.com | The Workplace | StackExchange.Workplace |
| https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com | The Workplace Meta | StackExchange.Workplace.Meta |
| https://cstheory.stackexchange.com | Theoretical Computer Science | StackExchange.Cstheory |
| https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com | Theoretical Computer Science Meta | StackExchange.Cstheory.Meta |
| https://tor.stackexchange.com | Tor | StackExchange.Tor |
| https://tor.meta.stackexchange.com | Tor Meta | StackExchange.Tor.Meta |
| https://travel.stackexchange.com | Travel | StackExchange.Travel |
| https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com | Travel Meta | StackExchange.Travel.Meta |
| https://tridion.stackexchange.com | Tridion | StackExchange.Tridion |
| https://tridion.meta.stackexchange.com | Tridion Meta | StackExchange.Tridion.Meta |
| https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com | Ukrainian Language | StackExchange.Ukrainian |
| https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com | Ukrainian Language Meta | StackExchange.Ukrainian.Meta |
| https://unix.stackexchange.com | Unix & Linux | StackExchange.Unix |
| https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com | Unix & Linux Meta | StackExchange.Unix.Meta |
| https://ux.stackexchange.com | User Experience | StackExchange.Ux |
| https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com | User Experience Meta | StackExchange.Ux.Meta |
| https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com | Veganism & Vegetarianism | StackExchange.Vegetarian |
| https://vegetarianism.meta.stackexchange.com | Veganism & Vegetarianism Meta | StackExchange.Vegetarian.Meta |
| https://vi.stackexchange.com | Vi and Vim | StackExchange.Vi |
| https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com | Vi and Vim Meta | StackExchange.Vi.Meta |
| https://video.stackexchange.com | Video Production | StackExchange.Audio |
| https://video.meta.stackexchange.com | Video Production Meta | StackExchange.Audio.Meta |
| https://webapps.stackexchange.com | Web Applications | StackExchange.WebApps |
| https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com | Web Applications Meta | StackExchange.WebApps.Meta |
| https://webmasters.stackexchange.com | Webmasters | StackExchange.Webmasters |
| https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com | Webmasters Meta | StackExchange.Webmasters.Meta |
| https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com | Windows Phone | StackExchange.Windowsphone |
| https://windowsphone.meta.stackexchange.com | Windows Phone Meta | StackExchange.Windowsphone.Meta |
| https://woodworking.stackexchange.com | Woodworking | StackExchange.Woodworking |
| https://woodworking.meta.stackexchange.com | Woodworking Meta | StackExchange.Woodworking.Meta |
| https://wordpress.stackexchange.com | WordPress Development | StackExchange.Wordpress |
| https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com | WordPress Development Meta | StackExchange.Wordpress.Meta |
| https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com | Worldbuilding | StackExchange.Worldbuilding |
| https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com | Worldbuilding Meta | StackExchange.Worldbuilding.Meta |
| https://writing.stackexchange.com | Writing | StackExchange.Writers |
| https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com | Writing Meta | StackExchange.Writers.Meta |
| https://rus.stackexchange.com | Русский язык | StackExchange.Rus |
| https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com | Русский язык Meta | StackExchange.Rus.Meta |
| https://ja.stackoverflow.com | スタック・オーバーフロー | StackOverflow.Ja |
| https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com | スタック・オーバーフローMeta | StackOverflow.Ja.Meta |

Comment: That list has been generated semi-automatically with some jQuery on https://stackexchange.com/sites and some Excel formulas, coupled with manual adjustments. It's sorted by site name, and for those sites, the official name of their Meta *starts* with 'Meta'.

Comment: OK, that explains those, but 2nd column sorting disrupts https://mathoverflow.net/ and the alphabetical adjacency of sites: https://apple.stackexchange.com/ https://ham.stackexchange.com/ https://money.stackexchange.com/  https://patents.stackexchange.com/ https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/  https://stats.stackexchange.com/ https://crypto.stackexchange.com/  https://money.stackexchange.com/ https://fitness.stackexchange.com/  https://cooking.stackexchange.com/ https://dsp.stackexchange.com/ https://es.stackoverflow.com/ https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/ https://workplace.stackexchange.com/ -

Comment: Sorting on the first column (like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/327741#327741)) works too, but also suffers from e.g. Ask Ubuntu being separated from its own Meta.

Comment: From the [tag:data-explorer] tag **eventually** a SEDE query would be posted as an answer, this additional answer should be the output. --- The *written name* of the sites is most inconsistent, and really out of scope for this Q&A, but when remembering a site name do we remember "Workplace", "The Workplace" or the URL (asking rhetorically?); while for Raspberry Pi the "The" is missing. --- Perhaps filtering out "meta" from wherever it is in the string of the URL and sorting by the resulting alphanumeric would form the most natural grouping; in the manner by which each site is remembered. ???

Comment: But the single source of truth is now this post?

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q I already updated a dozen queries, so I hope so :)

Comment: Not that they can be used in a SEDE context, but perhaps add a note about the excluded (special) sites: [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/) and [Über Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/)? Are there other sites? Stack Apps *is* included, but it is special in some ways - without a meta site and *"Top Apps"*/*"Top Scripts"* sections

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/? I'll add a note about it. CS50 is not in SEDE either.

Comment: In terms of regularity of the URL (and DNS), [mathoverflow.net is an exception](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363018/is-array-overflow-a-stack-exchange-web-site#comment1211651_363023) (like the ["trilogy" sites](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/31/the-stack-overflow-trilogy/). And [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/tour)).

Comment: @Glorfindel is this still accurate? I think code golf has a new name in the meanwhile?

Comment: @Luuklag actually, it's still called Code Golf according to e.g. the website title.

Comment: "code golf & code challenges" (obfuscated as "CGCC") is in [the logo](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tour) for Code Golf. But it is just that, a logo.

Comment: Coming up ([same status](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390711/no-id-for-cs50-or-programming-language-design-and-implementation-on-stackexchang) as CS50?): *[Programming Language Design and Implementation](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/)*