# Is Array Overflow a Stack Exchange web site?

Tags: discussion, clone, copycat-sites

There's a site called Array Overflow at https://arrayoverflow.com. Is it legit? Its Facebook Page says nothing about the operator of the web site, and at the bottom of the site it just says (C) Array Overflow.

Comment: I don't see it in [the list of SE sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#name), so it's not a SE site.

Comment: Of course it’s not affiliated with Stack Exchange. They use _PHP_. They also use quite bad grammar and spelling in their _About us_ page.

Comment: Just another failed attempt to copy Stack Overflow. The site is essentially dead, About Me written with broken English, and all in all it's obvious it's not a professional website. Looks like private project of someone with spare time. Bottom line: nothing to worry about.

Comment: Also Stack Exchange wouldn't make two sites about programming.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is not a Stack Exchange site. You can find almost all sites [here](https://stackexchange.com/sites#name). There are a few more "secret" ones. But this isn't one of them.

Besides that there is only a limited set of domains used by Stack Exchange. Most sites are hosted as subdomains of stackexchange.com. Exceptions are the original trilogy sites: [StackOverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com), [SuperUser.com](https://superuser.com) and [ServerFault.com](https://serverfault.com). Besides those three there are [MathOverflow.net](https://mathoverflow.net) and [AskUbuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com) and the special case of [Stackapps.com](https://stackapps.com)

As far as the questions go, I googled some of them, and none appear to be copied from Stack Overflow, or any other SE site. They do however show some strong resemblance to other sites, but that is not something Stack Exchange has any business with.

They however certainly do their best to look like an Stack Exchange site, and hope to profit of the Stack Exchange / Stack Overflow name I guess.
If you for example look at the tabs on your browser they bear a lot of resemblance:
[image]

Another tell-tale sign is the footer of a site. The Stack Exchange network uses the same footer on all sites:
[image]

While the footer of Array Overflow looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Isn’t the list of StackExchange sites of kind of useless to verify if it is real or not when the list only lists „almost all“, because you will always have to ask yourself is it missing in the list because it is fake or secret or other reason?

Comment: “Secret” sites?! do tell!

Comment: @DeanWard CS50 for example.

Comment: @Luuklag Good call, yup, sites still in beta aren’t listed on se.com

Comment: And I have strong evidence there are some that are only available to staff members @DeanWard ;)

Comment: @DeanWard you mean private beta?

Comment: @Luuklag not sure what that "strong evidence" is, but as a member of staff I can categorically say I don't have access to any "secret" network sites :). We do have private and public betas that won't be listed on se.com, but that's the only network sites that aren't publicly listed (although they're generally on Area51). All our current beta sites are sub domains of `stackexchange.com` so the list of public network sites is a definitive list of anything that we own that hosts a Q&A site.

Comment: @DeanWard dev.stackexchange.com is one of those I guess

Comment: That’s not a production environment, I don’t know many companies that grant public access to their dev environments :)

Comment: @DeanWard - you said "we own", isn't it than a simple whois query a 100% sure way to figure it out, even if for some reason the domain isn't publicly listed? eg. `whois` for `superuser.com` (https://who.is/whois/superuser.com) vs `arrayoverflow` (https://who.is/whois/arrayoverflow.com) where `superuser` gives the information `Registrant Contact Information Organization Stack Exchange, Inc.` while `arrayoverflow` shows `ARRAYOVERFLOW LTD` ? Or are there domains that aren't owned by `Stack Exchange, Inc.`

Comment: @RandRandom yes, our domains are all registered with the legal entity so a `whois` is definitely the best way to know for sure

Comment: @DeanWard you might want to update the WhoIs for mathoverflow then ;) It is all in the name of `Domains By Proxy, LLC`

Comment: @Luuklag Mathoverflow is an oddity - they run our software and the DNS points at our infrastructure but we don’t own the domain :)

Comment: So there is no 100% fool-proof method @DeanWard ;)

Comment: @Dean totally odd, why is that? Any idea? Or maybe better start new question about it? (Mathoverflow domain not owned by SE)

Comment: @ShadowTheVaccinatedWizard there's a little bit on the [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathOverflow) page but tl;dr: it used to be an SE 1.0 site (a predecessor to our Enterprise product) and got migrated into the network when that product went away - we didn't have Enterprise at that time. I don't know the full background but that's the gist of it

Comment: @DeanWard - who has the pot of gold to buy back the domain? Re-phrased who could we get involved to "fix" this `oddity`? With stackexchange clones rather increasing than decreasing this should be "fixed" IMHO

Comment: Mathoverflow as I understand was never 'owned' by SE - and they have some kinda agreement with that. Also there's no space so clearly it can't be a stack overflow product :D

Comment: The mathoverflow.net domain is not owned by SE, but by MathOverflow. This was one of the conditions of the agreement under which MathOverflow joined the SE network. See https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4429/what-is-mathoverflows-agreement-with-stack-exchange.

Comment: The single source of truth for the site list is *[How can I get URLs and site names for a cross-site SEDE query?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359794/how-can-i-get-urls-and-site-names-for-a-cross-site-sede-query/359796#359796)*.