# Sites list link in recent Overflow blog post should have the view set to list

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, hyperlinks, stackexchange.com, blog

In the [*Check out the Stack Exchange sites that turned 10 years old in Q4*](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/12/01/check-out-the-stack-exchange-sites-that-turned-10-years-old-in-q4/) blog post, there is a link to the Stack Exchange sites list with the sort set to total "Question Per Day" (https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday).

This link will navigate properly only when your last view selection on that page was a *list view* (eg. https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list).

If your last selection was grid view instead, (https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=grid) the link from the blog post won't navigate to the intended "Sort by" filter.

If the URL has the `?view=list` bit appended to the end, then the view will be set correctly when the user clicks the link, ensuring that the page matches what's mentioned in the blog. It should be:

```
https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#questionsperday
```

instead of

```
https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday
```

Blog spot screenshot with URL:

[image: Blog spot screenshot with URL link]

Comment: The single source of truth for the site list is *[How can I get URLs and site names for a cross-site SEDE query?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359794/how-can-i-get-urls-and-site-names-for-a-cross-site-sede-query/359796#359796)*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you for reporting. The link has been fixed on the blog post.

Comment: I think use of the word *flagging* in the SE context is extremely specific and while on others sites "reporting", "flagging" and "signaling" are often used as synonyms I would advise rewording in this case to not cause any misunderstanding to readers.