# Does anyone have an account on every Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, user-accounts

Does anyone have an account on every Stack Exchange site? Also, why would anyone do that?

Bonus points for all of the Beta sites.

Comment: The first step would be using [the single source of truth for the site list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359794/how-can-i-get-urls-and-site-names-for-a-cross-site-sede-query/359796#359796).

Comment: How are you going to hand out bonus points? :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well - yes.

Community managers come to mind (for work reasons), but there are a lot of folks who help flag spam on sites they're not active in - with something like [Charcoal/SmokeDetector](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/06/25/how-does-spam-protection-work-on-stack-exchange/) and related extensions. It’s helpful for the communities as a whole. While I don't have accounts everywhere, I do have accounts on lots of sites just to flag spam.

Or someone got bored and decided to sign up everywhere.

Comment: Does anyone have an account everywhere including the beta sites?

Comment: CMs? :D Never really checked otherwise

Comment: @Leo I do, for reasons outlined in the answers.

Comment: @Leo - I'm not quite sure why you think the beta sites are so special... many of them have been around for years (though fewer now)... it's a misconception that beta means anything other than "still figuring out their scope a bit".

Comment: By bonus points I meant that it is harder to have on the beta sites as well.

Comment: @Leo It's not harder to have profiles on the beta sites. It's exactly the same.

Comment: By harder I mean you have to go to more sites. For example, it is harder to do 5 cakes than 3, even though they are the same

Answer (score 12):

It's a common theme in [Charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq), the chatroom for the [organization](https://charcoal-se.org/) which fights spam across the network. With the [association bonus](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141648/295232), you have enough reputation to cast spam flags on *every* site, so it makes sense to join them all. A couple of years ago, I wrote a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/628471/sites-where-a-user-doesnt-have-an-account-on) to facilitate this processs. (Please keep in mind SEDE is updated only once a week, on Sunday morning, so your newer accounts might not be visible yet. Also, private beta sites and Area 51 are not in SEDE.)

Comment: And thats where the association bonus is useful