# Would it be possible to add 301 redirects for Stack Exchange sites with unique domains?

Tags: feature-request, redirection

I visit a lot of *.stackexchange.com sites, and usually I type the address manually. Every now and then, I'll type (for example) superuser.stackexchange.com, only to be met with the "Site not found" message, and I'll think "Oh right..., that's superuser.com".

I think a simple 301 redirect for all sites with unique domains would help. It's not that many to begin with, and (I think) it's relatively simple to implement.

Comment: Alternative:  Search [in a list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359794/how-can-i-get-urls-and-site-names-for-a-cross-site-sede-query/359796#359796) and open. Bonus: The list is somewhat annotated.