# What is the best site to post questions about the Android mobile OS?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Specifically, asking about features, how can I enable or disable them and suggest or request new features?

Comment: Have you considered... [Android Stack Exchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Sure... except it was not obvious that such a site existed until you pointed it out now... The funny thing is that I actually posted there in the past. Thanks for the reminder. Please make this an answer.

Comment: I am a user of SE since the very beginning of SO. Still, sometimes it is hard to find the appropriate sites. Maybe it is a good idea to improve the network's search abilities?

Comment: There are already ways to search sites (e.g. the top-right site-switcher). There are also lists of all sites sorted by category (e.g. the All Sites page). Where else would you like that information to appear?

Comment: A simple text search on [the sites list](https://stackexchange.com/sites) would have been sufficient (e.g., invoked from [the profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current) on any site, *"Network profile"* (on the upper right) → *"All Sites"* (though it is now hidden on most sites under "Profiles")), but yes, an ***annotated*** list would be nice. The *about* pages for sites don't contain any real information. Slightly related: [The single source of truth for the site list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/359796)

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum - Yes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider [Android Stack Exchange](https://android.stackexchange.com/) for all (well, most) things Android.

I'd take a second and have a look at their [on-topic](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) guidance though and ensure the question you're about to ask is acceptable there. For example, it likely wouldn't be acceptable to try and request a feature there.