# MathJax processing issue - Strange behavior in the editor of "\:" in a formula

Tags: bug, editor, mathjax, markdown-preview, whitespace

I noticed that in some posts, the code of the equations ends with "\:.", but nor "\:", nor ":" themselves appear in the rendered equation (see, e.g., [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/301058/74868)). However, if I copy-paste such an equation, e.g.

```latex
$$V(t)U_t = U_t V(0) \quad \forall t \in \mathbb R\:,\tag{1}$$
```

into the editor of a new question, ":" is shown literally also in the rendered equation seen below the editor window. I see that "\:" represents a kind of space character, but why does it behave differently when I edit a post or add a question?

(I noticed also that in this question, the MathJax code isn't processed at all. Why?)

Comment: Does this only happen on Physics? You can specify your block's code using "``` lang-latex". This also works here. (See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109).)

Comment: `\:` produces a space. For instance, see egreg's [answer to "Math mode horizontal space difference between \ (backslash) and \; (backslash semicolon) and what to use for multiplication"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/144240) on TeX - LaTeX SE. If you want the colon to be rendered then you shouldn't use the backslash.

Comment: No, I want the colon *not* to be rendered. The problem is that is rendered below the "Add question" window (but not below the "Edit post" window.

Comment: Ah, I see. My bad, don't know how I missed that part of your post. Just curious, does adding two backslashes before the colon make it work?

Comment: @TheAmplitwist Yes, two backslashes seem to work in the "Add question" editor but they make wrong in the "Edit answer" editor. :(

Comment: Perhaps related on Mathematics Meta: (1) Willie Wong's [answer to "Using the align environment?"](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3526) and (2) ["Same code rendering two different matrices"](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35223)

Comment: What kind of space is `\:`? [The tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?page=1&tab=createdasc#tab-top) seemingly only lists `\,` (backtick + comma. Thin space) and `\;` (backtick + semicolon. Wider space). And `\quad` and `\qquad`. And implicitly escaping space (`\ `)? Perhaps they mistyped `\;` as `\:`?

Comment: (Slightly related: *[Which Stack Exchange sites use MathJax?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216606/which-stack-exchange-sites-use-mathjax)*. [Full site list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/359796) (incl. most of the hidden and special ones in notes))

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum In LaTeX `\:` is equivalent to the spacing that is inserted around a binary operator, as per the link I shared in a [comment above](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/386776/mathjax-processing-issue-strange-behavior-in-the-editor-of-in-a-formula#comment1289731_386776).